# PLSQL parsing using Oracle.VsDevTools.SqlAndPlsqlParser

Tags: oracle, visual-studio, parsing, plsql

I downloaded Oracle Developer Tools for Visual studio and explored the libraries (.dll). I need to parse the PLSQL scripts to get the SQL Statements in that and using the visitors to visit the nodes. I found Oracle.VsDevTools.SqlAndPlsqlParser library and explored further and tried to parse the PLSQL scripts. Please refer the below code.

```
string plSQLScript="CREATE TABLE Student(Age int);";
List<LexerToken> tokens=  LexerToken.Parse(plSQLScript, false, true);
```

But the above code gives tokens only, I need PLSQL parser.

Is there any possible way to parser the PLSQL scripts and get the sql statements. Also I need to explicit visit the sql statements like **CreateTableVisitor**, **CreateProcedureVisitor**, etc.

I already created the parser for TSQL files by exploring Microsoft SQL library called **Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom** and using the below mentioned code for parsing.

```
TSql100Parser parser = new TSql100Parser(true);
IList<ParseError> error;
using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(filePath))
{
TSqlFragment fragment = parser.Parse(tr, out error);
tr.Close();
}
```

And using **TSqlFragmentVisitor** to visit the sql statements. Please refer the below mentioned code.

```
public override void ExplicitVisit(CreateTableStatement node)
{
  //----Coding----
}
```

I want the same for PLSQL by using **Oracle.VsDevTools.SqlAndPlsqlParser** library.

Please let me know if there any possibility for this.

Thanks,Sivaprakash.

Answer (score 1):

With some reflection used it's possible. The parser, nodes and grammar classes are internal. I made small example for you:

```
private static Assembly odacDevAssembly = Assembly.Load("Oracle.VsDevTools.14.0");
private static Type parseNodeType = odacDevAssembly.GetType("Oracle.VsDevTools.SqlAndPlsqlParser.ParseNode");

void Main()
{
    var parserType = odacDevAssembly.GetType("Oracle.VsDevTools.SqlAndPlsqlParser.OracleSqlEarley");
    var parser = Activator.CreateInstance(parserType);

    const string sqlScriptText = "DECLARE x NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT DUMMY INTO :DUMMY FROM DUAL T1; x := 1; SELECT DUMMY INTO :DUMMY FROM DUAL T2; x := 2; INSERT INTO T3 (C) VALUES (1); x := 3; END;";
    var tokens = LexerToken.Parse(sqlScriptText);

    var parserGrammar = parserType.GetProperty("EarleyGrammar").GetValue(parser);

    var allSymbols = (string[])parserGrammar.GetType().GetField("m_vAllSymbols", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(parserGrammar);

    var sqlStatementIndex = -1;
    for (var i = 0; i < allSymbols.Length; i++)
    {
        if (allSymbols[i] == "unlabeled_nonblock_stmt")
        {
            sqlStatementIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    var parseTree = parserType.GetMethod("Parse").Invoke(parser, new object[] { sqlScriptText, tokens });
    //parseTree.GetType().GetMethod("PrintTree", new Type[] { parserGrammar.GetType() }).Invoke(parseTree, new object[] { parserGrammar });

    var commandNodes = GetDescendants(parseTree).Where(d => GetPayloadIn(d) == sqlStatementIndex);
    foreach (var commandNode in commandNodes)
    {
        var commandText = GetCommandText(commandNode, sqlScriptText, tokens);
        Console.WriteLine(commandText);
    }
}

private static string GetCommandText(object parseNode, string sqlScriptText, List<LexerToken> tokens)
{
    var from = (int)parseNodeType.GetProperty("From").GetValue(parseNode);
    var to = (int)parseNodeType.GetProperty("To").GetValue(parseNode) - 1;

    var begin = tokens[from].m_vBegin;
    return sqlScriptText.Substring(begin, tokens[to].m_vEnd - begin);
}

private static IEnumerable<object> GetDescendants(object parseNode)
{
    yield return parseNode;

    foreach (var child in GetChildren(parseNode))
        foreach (var descendant in GetDescendants(child))
            yield return descendant;
}

private static int GetPayloadIn(object parseNode)
{
    return (int)parseNodeType.GetProperty("PayloadIn").GetValue(parseNode);
}

private static IEnumerable<object> GetChildren(object parseNode)
{
    return (IEnumerable<object>)parseNodeType.GetMethod("Children").Invoke(parseNode, null);
}
```

UPDATE:

I'm not exactly sure what do you want to achieve but I hope it will be at least somehow helpful:

```
private static Assembly odacDevAssembly = Assembly.Load("Oracle.VsDevTools.14.0");
private static Type parseNodeType = odacDevAssembly.GetType("Oracle.VsDevTools.SqlAndPlsqlParser.ParseNode");

void Main()
{
    var parserType = odacDevAssembly.GetType("Oracle.VsDevTools.SqlAndPlsqlParser.OracleSqlEarley");
    var parser = Activator.CreateInstance(parserType);

    const string sqlScriptText = "DECLARE x NUMBER; BEGIN SELECT DUMMY INTO :DUMMY FROM DUAL T1; x := 1; SELECT DUMMY INTO :DUMMY FROM DUAL T2; x := 2; INSERT INTO T3 (C) VALUES (1); x := 3; END;";
    var tokens = LexerToken.Parse(sqlScriptText);

    var parserGrammar = parserType.GetProperty("EarleyGrammar").GetValue(parser);

    var allSymbols = (string[])parserGrammar.GetType().GetField("m_vAllSymbols", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(parserGrammar);

    const int sqlStatementIndex = 4453; // unlabeled_nonblock_stmt

    var parseTree = parserType.GetMethod("Parse").Invoke(parser, new object[] { sqlScriptText, tokens });
    //parseTree.GetType().GetMethod("PrintTree", new Type[] { parserGrammar.GetType() }).Invoke(parseTree, new object[] { parserGrammar });

    var commandNodes = GetDescendants(parseTree)
        .Select(n => ParseNodeFactory.CreateNode(n, sqlScriptText, tokens))
        .Where(n => n != null);

    var visitor = new GrammarNodeVisitor();
    foreach (var commandNode in commandNodes)
    {
        commandNode.Accept(visitor);
    }
}

public static class ParseNodeFactory
{
    private const int queryBlockIndex = 3849; // query_block
    private const int insertIndex = 3136; // insert

    public static IParseNode CreateNode(object parseNode, string sqlScriptText, List<LexerToken> tokens)
    {
        var symbolIndex = GetPayloadIn(parseNode);
        var parseData = new ParseData { ParseNode = parseNode, SqlScriptText = sqlScriptText, Tokens = tokens };
        switch (symbolIndex)
        {
            case queryBlockIndex:
                return new QueryBlock { ParseData = parseData };
            case insertIndex:
                return new Insert { ParseData = parseData };
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

public class GrammarNodeVisitor : IParseNodeVisitor
{
    public void VisitQueryBlock(QueryBlock queryBlock)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Visited query block: {GetCommandText(queryBlock.ParseData.ParseNode, queryBlock.ParseData.SqlScriptText, queryBlock.ParseData.Tokens)}");
    }

    public void VisitInsert(Insert insert)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Visited insert command: {GetCommandText(insert.ParseData.ParseNode, insert.ParseData.SqlScriptText, insert.ParseData.Tokens)}");
    }
}

public interface IParseNodeVisitor
{
    void VisitQueryBlock(QueryBlock queryBlock);

    void VisitInsert(Insert insert);
}

public interface IParseNode
{
    ParseData ParseData { get; }
    void Accept(IParseNodeVisitor visitor);
}

public class ParseData
{
    public object ParseNode { get; set; }
    public string SqlScriptText { get; set; }
    public List<LexerToken> Tokens { get; set; }
}

public class QueryBlock : IParseNode
{
    public ParseData ParseData { get; set; }

    public void Accept(IParseNodeVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.VisitQueryBlock(this);
    }
}

public class Insert : IParseNode
{
    public ParseData ParseData { get; set; }

    public void Accept(IParseNodeVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.VisitInsert(this);
    }
}

private static string GetCommandText(object parseNode, string sqlScriptText, List<LexerToken> tokens)
{
    var from = (int)parseNodeType.GetProperty("From").GetValue(parseNode);
    var to = (int)parseNodeType.GetProperty("To").GetValue(parseNode) - 1;

    var begin = tokens[from].m_vBegin;
    return sqlScriptText.Substring(begin, tokens[to].m_vEnd - begin);
}

private static IEnumerable<object> GetDescendants(object parseNode)
{
    yield return parseNode;

    foreach (var child in GetChildren(parseNode))
        foreach (var descendant in GetDescendants(child))
            yield return descendant;
}

private static int GetPayloadIn(object parseNode)
{
    return (int)parseNodeType.GetProperty("PayloadIn").GetValue(parseNode);
}

private static IEnumerable<object> GetChildren(object parseNode)
{
    return (IEnumerable<object>)parseNodeType.GetMethod("Children").Invoke(parseNode, null);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will explore this :)

Comment: I want to create a Visitor class to visit each nodes and statements in that sql file, like Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom library TSqlFragmentVisitor. Is it possible for this library?

Comment: Absolutely, just try to be inventive. Indexes for all terminals and non-terminals are defined in allSymbols array, so pick symbols you want make interface which implementation will wrap parse node of a specific index, Which basically makes the nodes strongly typed. Then you create a visitor like for any other set of inherited classes. Actually you can generate the classes using T4 so you definitely don't need to type them manually (if you want to visit more than handful of them). This would be at least my first shot there are many approaches for this kind of problem.

Comment: If possible please provide me sample code for just one visitor like "CreateTableStatementVisitor", or just provide some simple hint. It will be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much. I want to write custom static code analyzer. For example, Rule #1: "Should not use CURSOR inside stored procedure", So I need to read .sql file and parse it and visit each stored procedures inside the .sql file and then visit if any CURSORS declared then I need to show warning to the user like " Line Number : # and Stored Procedure Name: ## has CURSOR declared"